# одновременный скролл 2 RecyclerView на одном экране

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть 2 RecyclerView в активити. Количество заполняемых элементов одинакова. **Как можно реализовать одновременный скролл этих RecyclerView?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если минимальный **API выше 21** то так:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Если **ниже 21**, то тогда флажки android:nestedScrollingEnabled добавь через код

```
recycler_view_1.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
recycler_view_2.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```